# Python / Pandas running total

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
Date          BrokenRule    Cost
2014-01-01    abc           100
2014-01-02    xyz           50
2014-01-03    abc           40
2014-01-04    xyz           70
2014-01-05    xyz           10
```

I need to calculate the running `Cost` total of each `BrokenRule` which will then be plotted as linecharts.

If I were to calculate the running total across all BrokenRule's I would simply use `cumsum()`. However I can't seem to figure out a way to show a running total for each `BrokenRule`. Perhaps by using `cumsum()` and `groupby()` together but I haven't been able to get that to work.

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Comment: And `df.groupby('BrokenRule')['Cost'].cumsum()` does not work?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @joris but unfortunately that does not work

Comment: Good you already got a working answer, but as a suggestion: if you say "that does not work", you should "show" what doesn't work, eg at least give an error message or the wrong vs expected output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code

```
df.set_index("BrokenRule", append=True).unstack().fillna(0).cumsum()
```

results in

```
            Cost     
BrokenRule   abc  xyz
Date                 
2014-01-01   100    0
2014-01-02   100   50
2014-01-03   140   50
2014-01-04   140  120
2014-01-05   140  130
```

By unstacking the newly added `BrokenRule` level of the index we make a column for each individual value of that column. Filling with zeros and then doing `cumsum` (column-wise by default) gives the hopefully expected result.

Comment: Excellent that works perfectly, thanks @filmor. It is going to take me some time to try and understand exactly how this works.

Comment: Just do it step-by-step, the only non-trivial part is the `unstack`-call.